# VBA to copy multiple offset cells

Tags: vba, excel, offset

This is probably basic but I can't find how to do it.

I want to select a cell and an offset cell 3 cells to the right. Not any in between. So if I selected A2, it would copy A2 and A5.

I've managed to do one or the other but can't work out how to combine. I am a beginner.

Thanks for the replies so far. Realise I worded my question wrong. I want to copy whichever cell is selected in column A and the corresponding cell on the same line in column E I have this so far but I can't work out how to get the code to do both at the same time

```
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
    ActiveCell.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Show your effort! :-)

Comment: You need to show some code. Search for the `Range.Offset` method in VBA.

Comment: Also explain your question better. Do you want to copy A2 to A5? Or copy A2 and A5?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Try()
Dim Selected_, Paste_ As Range
On Error Resume Next
'Allow user to select cell
Set Selected_ = Application.InputBox("Please select cell you would like to copy", Type:=8).Select
'Copy user's selected cell
Selection.Copy
'Offset, to select column E with the same row as user's selection
Set Paste_ = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
'Paste value
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

This should help :)

Comment: I am a novice. This doesn't seem to do anything. I can see the logic but what action makes it work? I wanted to use a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: OK, I've worked out how to make it work. All it is doing is copying the selected cell and pasting into column "E"

Comment: What I want to do is copy the selected cell in column "A" and the corresponding cell in Column "E". Combine the 2 outputs so I can then copy that wherever I like using Ctrl+V.   The column "A" contains part numbers and column "E" contains prices. You might say put the prices in column "B" but there are good reasons for not doing this.

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont understand wht you are trying to say... @PaulNorris